# Realm error error. msync() failed in SharedRealm.cpp

Tags: android, database, transactions, realm, realm-mobile-platform

This is my code:

```
 Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(PSApplicationClass.Config);
final RealmLocation realmLocation1 = new RealmLocation(locEnd.getLatitude(), locEnd.getLongitude(), locEnd.getTime(), address, true);
            realmLocation1.setSpeed(locEnd.getSpeed());
            realmLocation1.setAccuracy(locEnd.getAccuracy());
            final int filterDistanceFinal = filterDistance;
            Log.i("", "GLOBAL intances  before addLocation:" + Realm.getGlobalInstanceCount(PSApplicationClass.Config));
            realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                @Override
                public void execute(Realm realm) {
                    RealmLocation realmLocation = realm.copyToRealm(realmLocation1);
                    Log.i("", "autopilot testcord onLocationChanged SAVED LOCATION:" + locEnd.getLatitude() + "," + locEnd.getLongitude());
                    Log.i("", "autopilot testcord TEST COORD HAS STARTED");
                    getRawLocations().add(realmLocation);
                    if (hasStarted) {
                        if (getDeparture_stop().getDeparture_time() == null) {
                            Long time = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
                            getDeparture_stop().setDeparture_time(time.intValue());
                        }
                    }
                    activeTrip.getSteps().set(lastTripStepIndex, TripStep.this);
                    filterIncomingLocations(context, filterDistanceFinal, realmLocation);
                    Log.i("", "autopilot testcord LOCATIONTEST COORDINATES SAVED: " + locEnd.getLatitude() + ", " + locEnd.getLongitude() + "....speed: " + locEnd.getSpeed() + "..... accuracy: " + locEnd.getAccuracy() + "RAW SIZE: " + getRawLocations().size());
                }
            });
realm.close();
```

It crashes when it tries to do realm.executeTransaction. Giving me the next error:

```
Fatal Exception: io.realm.exceptions.RealmError
Unrecoverable error. msync() failed: I/O error in /home/cc/repo/realm/release/realm/realm-library/src/main/cpp/io_realm_internal_SharedRealm.cpp line 260
```

Here:

```
io.realm.internal.SharedRealm.nativeCommitTransaction (SharedRealm.java)
io.realm.internal.SharedRealm.commitTransaction (SharedRealm.java:263)
io.realm.BaseRealm.commitTransaction (BaseRealm.java:359)
io.realm.Realm.commitTransaction (Realm.java:129)
io.realm.Realm.executeTransaction (Realm.java:1445)
nl.hgrams.passenger.model.trip.TripStep.addLocation (TripStep.java:418)
```

What can I do to fix this?

Realm version:

```
 dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:3.2.0"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0' // google-services plugin
}
```

Comment: What is your Realm version?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I added an edit stating my realm version

Comment: I don't really know what `msync()` does so I can't really help, nor am I sure if this is something that future Core versions address or not. I haven't seen this happen before.